# Split a list of sentence to words and append them to a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to split a sentence into words and have each word as a value for the sentence. so:

```
{sent 1: ["hi","how"], sent 2:["hello","i'm"]}
```

This is my code:

```
def get_maps(corpus):
vocab= {}
ind = len(corpus)
for line in corpus.values:
    for line[0] in line:
        print(line[0])
        for i in range(ind):
            sents = []
       
            
            vocab[i].append(line[0].lower().split())
        

return vocab
```

But this code returns a key error. When I just equate

```
vocab[i] = (line[0].lower().split())
```

I get the same value for every key.

My corpus is a datafame of sentences.

Comment: It'd be better if you could add a few rows of your `dataframe` as well in the question..

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you're overwriting the previous sentence(s) with multiple for loops. Here is a working example with just one loop:

```
import pandas as pd
sents = ["hi my name is retroflake", "this is a sample test case"]
df=pd.DataFrame(sents)
d={}
counter = 0
for sent in df.values:
    counter +=1
    d['sent {}'.format(counter)]=list(sent[0].split())
print(d)
```

And this is the output for the above snippet:

{'sent 1': ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'retroflake'], 'sent 2': ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'test', 'case']}

Answer (score 0):

You can't append to a list which doesn't exist in your dict.
You have to either use a defaultdict,with a list keyword is passed in as default_dict argument.
Or you have to use a normal dict inside try-except statement block

```
import collections
def get_maps1(corpus):
    vocab=collections.defaultdict(list)

    ind = len(corpus)
    for line in list(corpus.values()):
        for line[0] in line:

            for i in range(ind):
                sents = []


                vocab[i].append(line[0].lower().split())
```

Check the 4th statement.You have to make dict value iterable inroder to loop over.Simply calling values will return only the in-built method 'values'

You may use a try-except block if you wanna go for a normal dict

```
d1={1: ["hi","how"], 2:["hello","i'm"]}
vocab={}
for line in list(d1.values()):
        ind=len(d1)
        for line[0] in line:
            print(line[0])
            for i in range(ind):
                sents = []

                try:
                    vocab[i].append(line[0].lower().split())

                except:
                    #since key is absent a new key is created for first found list item
                    vocab[i]=[line[0].lower().split()]
```